# How can I draw the skewed normal distribution curve

Tags: normal-distribution, means, median

If its of real importance, I am trying to plot the data on `gnuplot`.
I have the following of some experimental data, obtained by `octave`:

- mean: $\overline{\mu} = 0.6058$
- median: $\tilde{\nu} = 0.6364$
- std: $\sigma_x = 0.1674$
- variance: $\sigma^2 = 0.028$
- skewness $= 0.3131$

I am trying to plot them, but AFAIK, the normal distribution does not account for skewness (left or right). 
I am using the typical Gaussian curve function:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma_x \cdot \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{- \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

How can I account the change in the curve shape, for my given skewness?
For this data-set it is obvious that there exists a difference from median to mean, and I would like to plot that.

Comment: So, [skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) is ok  for you?

Comment: I guess so. How can I calculate it though, I find the second part confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) with parameters $(ξ,ω,α)$ which can be estimated from the given data. If we set $δ=\dfrac{α}{\sqrt{1+α^2}}$, then the mean, variance and skewness of the skew normal distribution are given by (see the link)

1. mean: $ξ+ωδ\sqrt{\dfrac2π}$
2. variance: $ω^2\left(1-\dfrac{2δ^2}{π}\right)$
3. skewness: $\dfrac{4-\pi}{2} \dfrac{\left(\delta\sqrt{\dfrac2\pi}\right)^3}{ \left(1-\dfrac{2\delta^2}{\pi}\right)^{3/2}}$

Substitute your known values for the mean, variance and skewness to find proper values for the parameters $(ξ,ω,α)$ of the distribution. Approximate values will do (you do not need to solve exactly), because you are based on a sample, and the distribution that you will find does not need to fit exactly to the sample. So, trial and error (with a computer), may help, since this is not an easy to solve system.

---

Start from the formula of the skewness which depends only on $δ$. That is solve

$$0.3131=\dfrac{4-\pi}{2} \dfrac{\left(\delta\sqrt{\dfrac2\pi}\right)^3}{ \left(1-\dfrac{2\delta^2}{\pi}\right)^{3/2}}$$
to find (approximately $δ$). From $δ$ you can find directly $α$. Now, go to the variance and solve $$0.028=ω^2\left(1-\dfrac{2δ^2}{π}\right)$$
to find $ω$. Use the value for the $δ$ that you already have. Finally, use the formula for the mean (with $ω, δ$ known) to find $ξ$ in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am yet now even more confused. Are you referring to the equation `f(x)` at the wikipedia link? I understand `ξ,ω,α` are the parameters for that function which I must calculate, but how do these relate to mean, variance and skewness? Should I solve each formula such that it equals my mean, variance and skewness (on the left hand side)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. To leave the function (pdf) aside and solve each formula to equal your value (on the left hand side) as you said. You do not need to solve exactly but approximately.

Comment: Should I solve first for $\delta$ using my skewness, then for $\omega$ using the $\delta$ and variance, then for $\xi$ using mean, $\omega$ and $\delta$, and finally for $\alpha$ ?

Comment: If you find $δ$ then you already have $α$. For the rest, yes exactly see my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much Stef, very much appreciated, happy new year :-)

Comment: You too, happy new year!